# Limit data in Flask Restless

Tags: python, rest, flask

how can I limit amout of rows/objects returning by calling an endpoint?

```
http://localhost:8111/api/food_order?q={"filters": 
[{"name":"user_id","op":"==","val":1188}, 
{"name":"date","op":">","val":"2018-05-01"}]}
```

I need only last 6 rows from this query. Thanks

Comment: See the [docs](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pagination.html).

Comment: Read the docs for `limit`: https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/searchformat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I figured that out. Hope that will help some1 :D

```
http://localhost:8111/api/food_order?q={"limit":6,"filters": 
[{"name":"user_id","op":"==","val":1188}, 
{"name":"date","op":">","val":"2018-05-01"}]}
```

so its  simply `"limit": 6`  inside q param